# Error: Only one usage of each socket address is normally permitted

Tags: bash, sockets, go, git-bash

I have been using Go/Golang for a while. Every time I need to compile code I simply type `go run *.go` into Git bash. When I needed to terminate I used `CTRL+C`. And if I need to compile again I would use the same command `go run *.go`. Recently for some reason when I press `CTRL+C` it shows as if it terminated,but when I write again `go run *.go` it complains by saying `Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`
. And I open task manager and see on `main.exe` is on background processes. I end by hand and call this again it works. How can fix that so it terminates as before when I click on `CTRL+C`?

Comment: Without seeing your code it is very hard to help you out. Please post the code that you are experiencing problems with.

Comment: But it has nothing to do with my code. This is the same code. I haven't changed it since beginning.

Comment: @TuralƏsgərov: Stop using `go run`, then compile and execute your code normally. Something you've changed is preventing the child process from getting a signal or being interrupted leaving it running, but you can easily avoid the situation altogether.

Comment: @JimB But I don't want to build every time. `Go run` works very well for me.